# Allow only integer value in NumericUpAndDown Mahapp doesn't working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using the Framework `Mahapps.Metro`, in the documentation for disable the decimal value there is a property: `HasDecimals`, I set it to `False` but if I type: `5.01` the control allow me to insert this value. Maybe it's a bug?

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown x:Name="Timer" Minimum="5" Value="15" HasDecimals="False" Maximum="1440"  />
```

Also I want ask how can I disable the scientific value, so accept only integer. Is possible do this via XAML? Or How can I do this behind code?

Comment: Try to change stringformat to F3

Comment: @Gilad `stringformat`? In the XAML? I don't know this property

Comment: It is a property like `HasDecimals`

Comment: In the pre release I managed to disable the decimal value, but still remain the problem of scientific number, I want that the user insert only number not letters for scientific number, there is a way for doing this? @EmperorAiman

Comment: I dont think i can help u on that one as i have not used numericupdown before. Hope someone else helps you

Answer (score 5):

Was looking for this as well recently but thought I'd share what I found for anyone else that's looking. The `HasDecimals` property will be removed in an future release, thus you should use the `NumericInputMode`property instead like below.

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown Value="50" Interval="1" NumericInputMode="Numbers"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this works for me

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Interval="1" HasDecimals="False"/>
```

[image]